# Converted .wav file to C code not outputting sound in ARM processor

Tags: c, assembly, audio, arm

I'm currently coding a project using the ARM processor. The code is written in C, and I want to play a sound. I have this bit of code here:

```
#include <stdbool.h>


    void sound(int buffer[], int BUF_SIZE){
    volatile int * audio_ptr = (int *) 0xFF203040; // audio port address
int fifospace; 
    int buffer_index = 0;
int left_buffer[BUF_SIZE];
int right_buffer[BUF_SIZE];

fifospace = *(audio_ptr + 1); // read the audio port fifospace register
if ( (fifospace & 0x000000FF) > 96) // check RARC, for > 75% full
{
/* store data until the audio-in FIFO is empty or the memory buffer is full */
while ( (fifospace & 0x000000FF) && (buffer_index < BUF_SIZE) )
{
 *(audio_ptr + 2)= buffer[buffer_index]; //Leftdata
 *(audio_ptr + 3) = buffer[buffer_index]; //Rightdata
++buffer_index;
fifospace = *(audio_ptr + 1); // read the audio port fifospace register
}
}
}

int main(void){
int die_buffer[26112] = {...}; 

int die_buf_size = 26112;    
 sound(die_buffer,die_buf_size);

}
```

I have used a sample `die_buffer` array that works and can output sound. I tried converting my own `.wav` file to C code by using a program called [Wav2Code](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/WAVToCode.shtml). I uploaded my `.wav` file (it plays a G note) and selected 16 bits, 1 channel, mix to mono and saved it as a C code. I took the array it outputted in the form of:

```
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 48651

unsigned char data0[NUM_ELEMENTS] = {
128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, ...}
```

And set it equal to my `die_buffer`array. However, when I ran the code, no sound came out. Please help! I have no idea how to convert a `.wav` file correct to C so that it can work with the processor.

**Edit:** I got my `.wav` file using Audacity. I recorded a sound, and I exported it as a `.wav` and saved it as a "signed 16-bit PCM" (since saving it as a 32-bit float PCM didn't work on WaveToCode). I set the project rate to 48000Hz, mono and I exported with those parameters. 
[image: Image of my Audacity export parameters]

Then, I use WaveToCode to change it to C code. Here are the parameters I used (mixed it to mono).

[image: Image of my WaveToCode export parameters]

I also talked to someone and they said that the processor expects a **32-bit signed integer samples at a 48kHz sampling rate**, and I'm not sure if I managed to convert to that correctly. Hopefully this edit helped clarified what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: are all of the numbers 128?

Comment: There's a lot of setup that needs to be done before you can start outputting samples. You haven't shown any of that. And without detailed information about your hardware, there's no way to know if you've done that correctly.

Comment: @immibis No, it just happened that the first few lines I showed were 128.

Comment: @user3386109 I added an edit which has pictures of what I did. Hopefully this clarifies my question. Thanks.

Comment: `int` is signed 32-bit on ARM.  But your 16-bit PCM data is `int16_t`.  (Assuming the endianness matches).  Also, your code is horribly indented, making it hard to read.

Comment: You should ask that someone what the full scale range is on those **32-bit signed integer samples**. Also, your `unsigned char data0` array isn't 16-bit PCM, nor is the `die_buffer`. So it's not at all clear what your actual data is.